# How to increase the font size of a legend?

Tags: r

Or even the words in the plot itself? Any hints on that are welcome.

```
 dat <- selectByDate(mydata, year = 2003)
 dat <- data.frame(date = mydata$date, obs = mydata$nox, mod = mydata$nox)
 dat <- transform(dat, month = as.numeric(format(date, "%m")))
mod1 <- transform(dat, mod = mod + 10 * month + 10 * month * rnorm(nrow(dat)),model = "model 1")
 mod1 <- transform(mod1, mod = c(mod[5:length(mod)], mod[(length(mod) - 3) :
length(mod)]))
 mod2 <- transform(dat, mod = mod + 7 * month + 7 * month * rnorm(nrow(dat)),
model = "model 2")
mod.dat <- rbind(mod1, mod2)
```

Comment: I assume the data preparation steps are irrelevant to the actual question about font size. Just `dput` a small subset of "mod.dat" instead. See e.g. [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much of this appears to have been hard coded, so I don't think modifying this plot will be easy in general. In the specific case of the legend text, you can modify some arguments in the plot object after creating it:

```
out <- TaylorDiagram(mod.dat, obs = "obs", mod = "mod", group = "model")
out$plot$legend$right$args$key$text$cex <- 1.5
out$plot$legend$right$args$key$cex.title <- 1.5
```

I don't see anything similar that only applies to the text in the plot itself. To modify that you'd likely have to dig further into the code itself and modify it to get the specific results you want.

Indeed, digging further, much of the details of the plot are taking place in custom panel functions `panel.taylor.setup` and `panel.taylor` in which almost all of the specific sizes of things are hard coded.